# Is it posible to drag and drop with the finder(mac) using MAUI

Tags: c#, .net, maui, mac-catalyst, .net-maui

Using MAUI for Mac Catalyst is there a want to drag a file from the finder and then when drop it over the application it open it according to the internal rules of the app?

Comment: There's a similar issue on the .NET MAUI Blazor App about the `drag and drop` gesture. It may be a new feature request for this scenario, you can raise a thread in [this link](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/new/choose).